# Scala tail recursion error

Tags: scala, exception, tail-recursion

Below is a simple 'repeat' method I am trying to write using tail recursion. The sole purpose of this function is to just repeat the giving string back to back 'n' amount of times.

I.e. repeat("Hello",3) = "HelloHelloHello"

But for whatever reason I am getting a 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' and I am not sure why.

P.S. This is a homework assignment so if I could just be pointed in the right direction instead of a straight answer that would be cool!

```
  def repeat(s: String, n: Int): String = {
    def tailRepeat(str: String, x: Int): String = x match {
      case `n` => str
      case _ =>  val repeatString = s + str
      tailRepeat(repeatString, (x + 1))
    }
    tailRepeat(s, 0)
  }
```

Comment: What line does the exception get thrown at? Are you sure it is in this code? It seems to compile and run (mostly) fine for me - just an out-by-one error (`repeat("Hello",3)` gives `"HelloHelloHelloHello" for me).

Comment: Ya, It was throwing that error at the line where repeat is fine. But I just came back to it and now it works. I truly feel stupid as it works now, but I don't know what I did to make it work. As I changed nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are making this a little too complex. For one thing you don't really need pattern matching at all, you have a counting variable that tells you how many times to repeat your string, using that would simplify your code greatly. Also it is usually more straightforward to count down and not up:

```
def repeat(s: String, n: Int): String = {
    def tailRepeat(str: String, x: Int): String = {
        if(x == 0) str
        else       tailRepeat(str + s, x - 1)
    }
    tailRepeat(s, n - 1)
}

println( repeat("hello", 3) );
// hellohellohello
```

Comment: I have not tested this solution, but the only problem with this is, if the use passes in "0" for the number of repeats this would not work. I think this would just need to be changed ever so slightly to count for that edge case.

Comment: very true, nice catch; but the general idea stays the same.